# dynamically select a javascript object attribute

Tags: javascript

[How] can I achieve the following?

```
var object = new Object();
object.field1 = "test1";
object.fiedl2 = "test2";

function showSpecificField(fieldName){
    //get the field Name passed in to function from object
    //something like: return object.fieldName ???
}

alert(showSpecificField("field2"));// should alert the text "test2"

alert(showSpecificField("field1"));// should alert the text "test1"
```

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Use [square bracket notation](http://www.dev-archive.net/articles/js-dot-notation/)

```
var baz = 'bar';
foo['bar'] === foo.bar === foo[baz]
```

Comment: Thanks! - I have to wait another 10 minutes to accept your answer though... then i'll have "999" rep, that's kinda cool... although being able to have exactly 1000 would be cooler...

Comment: out of curiosity, is there any advantage of using `foo.bar` over `foo["bar"]` ?

Comment: Faster to type, shorter, easier to read, doesn't involve generating extra strings.

Comment: Possibly, but probably not significantly.